# how to getDrawingCache() with wallpaper

Tags: android, window, android-wallpaper

My application is a launcher, now I need a bitmap of current view.
Launcher's view can be retrived by getDrawingCache(), like following

```
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screen_w, screen_h, Config.ARGB_8888 );       
   View decorview = getWindow().getDecorView(); 
   decorview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
   bitmap = decorview.getDrawingCache();
```

But the bitmap is only of launcher'view, NOT containing wallpaper.

How can I get the bitmap with wallpaper ?

Comment: yes, device background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I had to say there is NO single API provide this function, user has to compound two bitmap, one is wallpaper part, the other is launcher's desktop view.
Generally, launcher extends wallpaper to several screens, so we have to get wallpaper's visible part.

Following is how I do:

```
    //get wallpaper's visible part
    //@param screenCount  how many screens launcher has
    //@param screenCurrent  current screen index
    Bitmap wallpaper = 
       ((BitmapDrawable) WallpaperManager.getInstance(context).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    float step = 0;
    step = (wallpaper.getWidth() - w) / (screenCount - 1);
    Bitmap wallpaperCurrent = 
    Bitmap.createBitmap(wallpaper, (int)(screenCurrent * step), 0, w, h);

    //get launcher's visible view bitmap
    View decorview = context.getWindow().getDecorView();     
    decorview.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap desktopBitmap = decorview.getDrawingCache(); 

    //compound bitmaps
    Bitmap compoundBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(compoundBitmap);  
    canvas.drawBitmap(wallpaperCurrent, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(desktopBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.restore();

    // return compoundBitmap
```

Comment: It'll not work perfectly. In this above code, to get x coordinate of wallpaper, you are dividing wallpaper width with number of screens. That idea is good but the problem is that wallpaper does not scroll completely to left or right with respect of workspace. That's why it'll not give you actual coordinates of  wallpaper.